# Error de timezone con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

estoy obteniendo un registro con su timestamp created_at y updated_at que se guardan con la fecha exacta en mysql todo normal ahi, pero cuando quiero obtener el listado en el frontend me lo muestra con otra fecha.

primeramente configure el config/app.php `'timezone' => 'America/La_Paz',` y nada me sale la hora adelantada por 4 en la respuesta que contiene el created_at y updated_at.

luego intente ver que fecha muestra el sistema y veo este gran problema:

si ejecuto:  `echo now()." - "; return(now());`

obtengo estas 2 fechas: **2020-10-16 19:59:08** - "2020-10-16T23:59:08.868845Z"

mi consulta `Nota::where('user_id', auth()->id())->get()` me devuelve los datos created_at y updated_at
con el timezone que se parece al de la derecha y lo correcto seria que use el timezone que esta a la izquierda, pero como ven obtengo 2 fechas completamente distintas usando la misma variable de laravel.

Alguien sabe por que cuando hago un echo me muestra una fecha y con return otra.

con el timezone por defecto de laravel `'timezone' => 'UTC',`  me muestra las 2 fechas equivalentes: **2020-10-17 00:28:08** - "2020-10-17T00:28:08.099556Z" pero con el timezone de America/La_Paz sale defectuosa.

Comment: Me parece que la segunda viene de la base de datos, tal vez ahi debe ser el cambio que tienes que hacer.

Comment: Claro, pero la hora ya estaba registrada, no va a cambiar se registro con una hora distinta, tal vez tu modificacion si funciono, pero de ahora en adelante.

Comment: No entiendo mucho el problema aquí. Si he entendido bien se trata de un dato guardado en la base de datos ¿no? Ese dato ya tiene su fecha y su hora cuando se guardó, por tanto, a partir de él puedes crear un objeto `DateTime` de PHP. No veo cuál sea el problema que comentas de la zona horaria y demás ¿?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En laravel, el helper `now()` es una instancia Carbon. La razón por la cuál obtienes valores distintos es debido a que `echo` imprime una cadena y `return` retorna la instancia Carbon en formato ISOString.

El siguiente código:

```
 echo now();
 return now();
```

Retorna:

```
2020-10-19 19: 28: 45"2020-10-20T00:28:45.366966Z"
```

Como ves, hay una diferencia de cierta cantidad de horas, lo cual es normal, ya que el formato ISOString usa la forma UTC.

Dado que `echo` imprime un string, internamente realiza lo siguiente: `now()->toDateTimeString()`.

Si haces lo siguiente:

```
 echo now();
 return now()->toDateTimeString();
```

Obtendrás el mismo resultados para ambos casos.

Comment: es una excelente respuesta que funciona en el backend, pero como seria en el caso de una api, al frontend le llegan las fechas incorrectas. ¿cual seria el equivalente a la funcion `toDateTimeString()` en JavaScript ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777055/6459968 Puedes leer un poco sobre eso allí. Sugiero convertir a un objeto Date y empezar desde allí. También puedes leer algo al respecto aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403486/add-or-subtract-timezone-difference-to-javascript-date en cuanto a timezones

Answer (score 0):

Yo en tu lugar verificaría la hora del servidor. Posteriormente cambiaría la zona horaria.

Y en blade que obtienes si haces {{ $variable->created_at }} ?

Comment: Si es raro, utilizas Carbon ?

Comment: Que pasa si agregas algo como created_at->diffForHumans();

Comment: Y si entiendo, en tu lugar setearía la fecha con Carbon y seguría buscando que causa el problema. Pero como solución provisoria es potable.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes prescindir de la configuración de la zona horaria de laravel y hacerlo con php nativo. Para ello puedes utilizar las siguientes funciones:

```
// Configurar una zona horaria
date_default_timezone_set($TU_TIME_ZONE);

// Obtener la zona horaria actual
date_default_timezone_get();

// Comprobar si la zona horaria es valida
public function is_valid_timezone($timezone) {
  return in_array($timezone, timezone_identifiers_list());
}
```

La zona horaria debe ser "seteada" antes de ejecutar cualquier método de conversión y/o obtención de la fecha en cuestión.

Ver la documentación de php para [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Lo ideal seria usar laravel o en su defecto el paquete de Carbon.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$timestamp = '2020-06-06 20:20:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/Stockholm');
$date->setTimezone('UTC');
```

Si no quieres estar configurando siempre la zona horaria puedes utilizar accessor y mutator de propiedades.

[Documentación de accessors y mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: Por eso incluí la forma "nativa" de php para setear zonas horarias. Quizá estás buscando el problema en el lado equivocado.  ¿En que versión de laravel estás trabajando?

Comment: Si te funciona lo de php puro quiere decir que al configurarlo en el servidor el problema igual debe solucionarse (posteriormente esas lineas de php se pueden eliminar). ¿Si quiera haz intentado implementar mi solución?

Comment: Si te olvidas del resultado y te enfocas en el proceso. ¿La zona horaria cambia oportunamente? Para este caso en particular, te retorna las horas correspondientes? (Puedes buscarlas la hora actual en google)

````
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
    echo 'Zona horaria actual ' . date_default_timezone_get();
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
    echo 'Zona horaria actual ' . date_default_timezone_get();
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
````